# Cancelling all request initiated from Axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, abortcontroller

We are following the repository pattern in our project where we have a dataLayer file that takes care of instantiating Axios and setting up the baseURL. Like so:

```
const LcAPI = axios.create();
```

We also have repository files that have multiple functions for different endpoints like so:

```
 let call;
 static async getData(
    queryParam1: number,
    queryParam2: number,
    requestBody: <RequestBody>
  ): Promise<ResponseBody> {

  if (call) {
      call.cancel("Only one request allowed at a time.");
    }
    return LcAPI.post(
     url,
      requestBody,
      getHeaderConfig()
    )
      .then((result) => {
        return result.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error on getPatternTrips API call : ' + error);
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

I am able to cancel any consecutive calls for a specific endpoint. But I need a way to cancel all previous requests made from the Axios instance.

For eg.
let's say the user has initiated the request to 5 different endpoints from multiple repository files, and I would need a way to cancel all five requests at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using axios interceptors.

For example:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    if (condition) {
        return {
            ...config,
            cancelToken: new CancelToken((cancel) => cancel('Cancel repeated request'))
        };
    };
});
```